# Laravel generate named routes from model data

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I want to SEO-up my laravel URLs, so I want to change `www.example.com/posts/32` to `www.example.com/posts/how-to-name-routes`

I see that I can manually name routes by chaining the `name()` method on the route, but I want the `name` to be automatically filled from the title of the post. The titles, however, contain spaces So my `Post` object would have the `title` `'How to name routes'` but the URL would be `www.example.com/posts/how-to-name-routes`

Do I need to implement my own string manipulation system or is this something Laravel handles already?

Comment: You can search for `laravel slug`

Comment: This might help [Creating Title Slugs with Laravel](https://medium.com/@kshitij206/creating-title-slugs-with-laravel-5bc59080cce6)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a unique **slug** column for your Posts table and then use that as the parameter in your routes e.g. `'/posts/{slug}'`.

You can add a mutator for this inside your Post model:

```
public function setTitleAttribute($title)
{
    $this->attributes['slug'] = str_slug($title);
    $this->attributes['title'] = $title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to implement a slug field on your `Post` model and use that as the key for Route Model Binding.

To slugify the post title, use Laravel's Muttators to convert the post title to a URL friendly slug.

To ensure that slugs are unique, you can append the timestamp to the slug, preserving SEO while removing conflicts on the column.

```
    /**

     * Set the post's slug.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setSlugAttribute()
    {
        $this->attributes['slug'] = Str::slug($this->attributes['title']) . dechex(time());
    }
```

After creating a slug field, you can bind it to the route by overriding the `getRouteKeyName` method in your `Post` model.

```
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
```

Your routes will become something like

```
    Route::get('posts/{post}', 'PostsController@getPost');
```

References:
Route Model Binding:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding
Slug Helper:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-str-slug
Eloquent Mutators:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators